# Rselenium problems finding an element

Tags: r, web-scraping, rselenium

I am new in Rselenium, I have been trying to scrape a web page with the following code:

```
library(reshape)
library(plyr)
library(RSelenium)

#start RSelenium
checkForServer()
startServer()
remDr <- remoteDriver()
remDr$open()

remDr$navigate(paste0("http://www.metrocuadrado.com/web/apartamentos/venta/c:bogota"))
```

I want to select the area categories (Área m2:), I don't have any problems selecting most of them (for example):

```
remDr$findElement(using = "xpath", paste0("//select[@name = 'arearango']/option[@value = 'Hasta 60']"))$clickElement()
```

But with the last category:

```
checkForServer()
startServer()
remDr <- remoteDriver()
remDr$open()

remDr$navigate(paste0("http://www.metrocuadrado.com/web/apartamentos/venta/c:bogota"))  

remDr$findElement(using = "xpath", paste0("//select[@name = 'arearango']/option[@value = '1001 o más']"))$clickElement()
```

I am having an error:

```
 Error:      Summary: NoSuchElement
 Detail: An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters.
 class: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException
```

I suppose that the problem has to do with the accent but I have not been able to solve it, how can I select this element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could solve it, it seems that R reads the word "más" as "mÃ¡s", I just change the letter á with Ã¡ and it works